# Invalid literal for float

Tags: python

I am having the hardest time figuring out why the scientific notation string I am passing into the float() function will not work:

```
time = []
WatBalR = []
Area = np.empty([1,len(time)])
Volume = np.empty([1,len(time)])
searchfile = open("C:\GradSchool\Research\Caselton\Hydrus2d3d\H3D2_profile1v3\Balance.out", "r")
for line in searchfile:
    if "Time" in line: 
        time.append(re.sub("[^0-9.]", "", line))
    elif "WatBalR" in line: 
        WatBalR.append(re.sub("[^0-9.]", "", line))
    elif "Area" in line:
        Area0 = re.sub("[^0-9.\+]", "", line)
        print repr(Area0[:-10])
        Area0 = float(Area0[:-10].replace("'", ""))
        Area = numpy.append(Area, Area0)
    elif "Volume" in line:
        Volume0 = re.sub("[^0-9.\+]", "", line)
        Volume0 = float(Volume0[:-10].replace("'", ""))
        Volume = numpy.append(Volume, Volume0)
searchfile.close()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-341de12bbc94> in <module>()
     13         Area0 = re.sub("[^0-9.\+]", "", line)
     14         print repr(Area0[:-10])
---> 15         Area0 = float(Area0[:-10].replace("'", ""))
     16         Area = numpy.append(Area, Area0)
     17     elif "Volume" in line:
    ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 0.55077+03
```

However, the following works:

```
float(0.55077+03)
3.55077
```

If I put quotes around the argument, the same invalid literal comes up, but I am tried to remove the quotes from the string and cannot seem to do so.

Comment: Where are you using scientific notation?  I don't see any.  NB: http://python-reference.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/float/scientific.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0.55077+03` is `0.55077` added to `03`. You need an `e` for scientific notation:

```
0.55077e+03
```

Answer (score 1):

`float(0.55077+03)` adds `3` to `.55077` and then converts it to a float (which it already is).

<sup>Note that this also only works on python2.x.  On python3.x, `03` is an invalid token -- the correct way to write it there is `0o3`...</sup>

`float('0.55077+03')` doesn't work (and raises the error that you're seeing) because that isn't a valid notation for a python float.  You need: `float('0.55077e03')` if you're going for a sort of scientific notation.  If you actually want to evaluate the expression, then things become a little bit trickier . . .